# Find all integers $x,y$ satisfying

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I had to find integers $x$ and $y$ satisfying the following equation:

$$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{3}$$

using the identity:

$$xy + bx + ay = (x+a)(y+b) - ab $$

I was able to end up with:

$$(x-3)(y-3)-9 = 0$$

Which yielded:

$$x = \frac{3y}{ (y-3)}$$

Then, I'd like to know if there's a specific way to find all INTEGERS solutions or I should compute the maximum integers I can to find solutions ?

Comment: Can you explain what your last question means? I'm not sure I follow

Comment: There are many more duplicates, see for example  the list [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3249191/find-all-integer-values-of-a-b-in-which-1-21-1-a-1-b).

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x$ and $y$ can't equal $3$. As you noticed, we can write the equation as:

$$x = \frac{3y}{y-3}$$

Since $x$ is an integer that means $y-3\ |\ 3y$, which implies $y - 3\ |\ 3y-3(y-3) = 9$. So $y - 3 \in \{\pm 1, \pm 3, \pm 9\}$. Testing all cases, we get the set of solutions:

$$\{(-6,2), (2,-6), (4,12), (12,4), (6,6)\}$$

The solution $(0,0)$ is discarded because of the form of the initial equation.

Answer (score 0):

As you did , $(x-3)(y-3)=9$ procced from here as $x,y$ are integers the possible choices are $x-3=-9,-3,-1,1,3,9$ respectively $y-3=-1,-3 ,-9,9,3,1$ thus all solutions are $(x,y)=(-6,2),(2,-6),(4,12),(6,6),(12,4)$. As $(0,0)$ is illegal as division by 0 is illegal.